# Neural network for AI playing Connect Four: how to encode inputs and outputs, and what kind of NN setup?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, activation-function, game-theory

Trying to understand how to build and train neural network based AI for games, and struggling to get some details straight.

Not even concerned yet with whether to use TensorFlow or something else or build my own. First I'm trying to grasp some basics such as what ranges to use, e.g. inputs between -1 and 1 or between 0 and 1, or how to represent input game situations and output moves.

Suppose I'm building a neural network to play [Connect Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four). Given a game situation, the AI is to generate an 'optimal move'. Let's say the optimal move is the move with the highest probability of eventually winning the game, assuming a reasonably smart opponent.

[image: Connect Four]

I guess the input would be 7 columns * 6 rows = 42 input neurons, each containing a value that represents either my color, or the opponent's color, or empty. 
How do I encode this? Does it make a difference whether I use:

- 0 = empty, 1 = my piece, 2 = opponent's piece
- 0 = empty, 0.5 = my piece, 1 = opponent's piece
- 0 = empty, 1 = my piece, -1 = opponent's piece

Or should I even use two times 42 = 84 input neurons, all binary/boolean, where 0=empty, 1s in the first 42 neurons represent my pieces, and 1s in the second 42 neurons represent the opponent's pieces?

What does the output look like? 7 neurons that each represent one column, getting an output value in the 0..1 range, and the AI's move would be the one with the highest value? Or just one output value ranging from 0 to 1, where roughly each 1/7th of the interval represents a particular column?

Also, how should I design my neural network, how many hidden layers? Classification or regression? [Sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) or [Relu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) or [tanh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) as activation function?

Intuitively, based on my limited experience with neural networks, I would say 2 or 3 hidden layers, each with two times the number of input neurons. No idea about the other considerations, I would just make stabs in the dark and trial and error.

Any feedback or suggestions to get me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you have not yet delved into AI gameplay, then might I suggest [OpenAI Gym](https://gym.openai.com/) as a starting place?

I believe starting with that foundation will allow you to 1) start building and learning with active participation right away, and 2) answer a lot of the foundational 'what-should-I-do?' questions that you have now - or at least at the time of asking this question, and then come back with the 'How-do-I' questions that we can really help you with here